# onEdit is triggered but not when I submit the Form

Tags: google-forms

I created a Form and bounded it to a Spreadsheet (with the Form responses). I wrote an onEdit function that is being triggered whenever the Spreadsheet is changed. The onEdit fills the Form dropdown based on the reposnses.
It works fine when I manually change a cell in the spreadsheet.
When I submit the Form (which changes the spreadhseet) the onEdit is not triggered.
Any idea?

Comment: You will have to use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to look for form submission in the sheet.

Comment: I added the following and it works fine.
Thanks!



function add_trigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit').forForm(FormApp.openById("1iq9MX3rxdRF5qsFNAgu1PQ1BI96VDvb8FhnSoGknFQs")).onFormSubmit().create();
}